# PHP Array shift/split but the first shift/split not working

Tags: php, arrays, apache

Im using a Apache to using a rewrite the URL's using this script.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./system.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

And this is how i split the requests for the array, so after each "/" make a new array item.

```
// split URL after "/" and making them to own array (start)
$q = split('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
array_shift($q); // We always have a first null value
$mode = array_shift($q);
// split URL after "/" and making them to own array (end)
```

But if im using it and the first "why-root-is-not-working" is not saved in the $q array!

```
http://example.com/why-root-is-not-working/test1/test2/
```

So if i want to show the array or call the different items the first one do not work!

```
print_r($q).'<br>';
echo '<br> testing if $q[-1] is working : '.$q[-1].'<br>'; 
echo '<br> testing if $q[0] is working : '.$q[0].'<br>'; //output test1 (now) but i want this to output "why-root-is-not-working"
echo '<br> testing if $q[1] is working : '.$q[1].'<br><br>'; //output test2 (now)
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: var_dump your array and paste it. do it before the `array_shift` call

Comment: try `array_filter(explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))`  - `split()` should be avoided as it's deprecated as of PHP5.3 and does not exist after PHP7.  Array filter will remove any falsy items from the array (including empty, null, 0 etc), you can also use a custom filter function to retain things like `[0]` if that is an issue.

Comment: Sorry but im 100% what you mean but i think you mean, I should changed the //$q = split('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); to $q = array_filter(explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ); but that do not work.. Now even test1 do not work! but test2 works on test1 $q[0]!

Comment: before the split : Array ( [q] => why-root-is-not-working/test1/test2/ after the new split you suggested : Array ( [0] => test2 ) the old split that is php 5 : Array ( [0] => test1 [1] => test2 [2] => )

Answer (score 0):

Haha.. I just woke up and all i needed was to add a "/" to the server uri!

```
$q = explode('/', '/'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

And i changed the slip to explode as its not exist any more in php7+